# How to set default remesh style of remesh modifier as block?

Tags: remesh

[image]

Since Blender's remesh of voxel always crash my blender, so I didn't need voxel remesh my model.

It's a serious problem since the new feature voxel remesh, why it still lasts for a long year.

Comment: Wow. 100 GB for Blender usage!? That's insane! What blender version are you using?

Comment: 2.9, 3.0 and 3.1@BlenderMaster15

Comment: Actually, it may not crash if you enough memory. I try to import a large scene over 100 million vertice, then it like crash can't do anything, but after 15 min, it done.

Answer (score 2):

There is not possible to set a modifier default setting except you modify the source code. But you can try to add a Weld modifier before the remesh.

Add a Weld modifier first, set distanace to 99999999, and then add a remesh, then remove the Weld.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is useful to some situations.

Comment: Thank you, good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Add the *Remesh* modifier in *Edit Mode* so that it is not calculated directly, then change the method and settings that will be applied when switching back to *Object Mode*.